# How to execute python code from perl program and use output of python code

Tags: perl, shell

I want to execute python script from perl code. I want to save python output to array and get some data from it. Python script will do some search in disk and locate files which I need. I will use that output and play with it in my next script.

I wrote some code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
my $opt_section;
my $opt_content;
my $opt_ver;
my $opt_help = 0;

 &GetOptions (
"help"          => \$opt_help,
"section:s"        => \$opt_section,
"content:s"        => \$opt_content,
"ver:s"      => \$opt_ver,
);

if ($opt_help) {
print "USAGE: file.pl -section <section> -content <content> -ver <ver> \n ";

exit;}
###################python script stats here ################
 my $py = `/home/priya/library/bin/find.py -filter test~${opt_section}_priya_${opt_ver}` ;


    print "output is $py \n";
```

code is executing python script and displaying output on the terminal screen. But it is not storing output to $py. Can you please hep me to direct all output to an array or scalar? later I want to use every line of python output.

Comment: `my @output = qx(... 2>&1)` (qx() is same as backticks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if find.py is outputting to STDERR. Try the following which redirects STDERR (filehandle 2) to STDOUT (filehandle 1) with `2>&1` and fills array `@python_output` with the resulting lines.

```
my @python_output = qx(/home/priya/library/bin/find.py -filter test~${opt_section}_priya_${opt_ver} 2>&1);
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2f_STRING_%2f for several examples of how to wrangle STDERR and STDOUT in pipes.